# Avoid organic supports merging *above* parts of the model

Tags: support-structures, prusaslicer

The current 2.6.0-alpha4 version of PrusaSlicer contains "organic" supports, similar to tree supports of other slicers.

One problem I am running into (and which also occurred with the classic supports, but now even more so, since the organic supports are by their nature much more able to grow "into" the model) is that sometimes support structures starting on different sides of the model merge *above* some part of the model. One example would be if a model has two horizontal struts above each other, both needing supports. The supports will grow correctly for the first strut (starting from the two sides of the strut on the plate), and then continue on to also support the second strut, but merging *above* the first strut; thus completely enclosing it.

It is then impossible to remove the support structure without possibly damaging the strut, unless the strut is much more massive than the support itself.

So, question time: Is there a way to block two strands of support starting somewhere from merging together further up?

As an example, see this image. Right in the center you see the two big supports, one growing from the front, the other from the back. A few layers upwards they will join and continue as a single big support. Imagine that there is some part of the model *below* that, and you see how hard it will be to get the support off without damaging the part (or at least being very annoying and time-consuming). I wish to somehow deny these two "towers" to grow together - whatever they will support further up could easily be achieved by one of them alone.

Note that this has nothing to do with the "support on build plate only" - both support towers do start on the build plate.

Also, I can of course use a support blocker to block supports for whatever feature is above this point, but that kind of defeats the purpose (assume that part further up absolutely does need support).

[image]

Comment: As you noted, this feature of the software is in the *alpha* stage. This would be where testers/users will submit bugs/crashes/problems to the developers in order to fix these issues. As development progresses, these problems could very well be resolved.